# aria-live not working with Firefox VoiceOver Mac

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I am using a Mac with Firefox and Voiceover. I noticed this morning Firefox displayed an information icon beside the address bar with the following message:

*"Accessibility support is partially disabled due to compatability issues with new Firefox features."*

I took a screenshot of it but I accidentally closed it before I could click the "learn more" link.

After this I noticed within my website game that the aria-live region is no longer being announced from VoiceOver.  I made a small snippet which has the same behavior.

note: the timeout and append of a space is just a work around to make screen readers not ignore if the same exact message is in the live region.

Is the aria-live not working in Firefox related to the information message that I saw about accessibility?

Edit:  *Should I expect it to start working after they fix something? or should I be trying to do something differently to make live areas work?*

Thanks for any information

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#controls").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    $("#alert-div").empty().append(" ");
    var text = $(this).attr("data-test");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
     $("#alert-div").empty().append(text);
    }, 100); 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-div" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <a href="javascript:;" data-test="Say this message">alert A</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" data-test="A different message">alert B</a>
</div>
```

It is currently working in Safari & Chrome.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767864/aria-live-in-firefox-not-read-by-screen-reader/65069022#65069022

Answer (score 1):

I **think** the answer is: aria-live isn't compatible with mac firefox.

From what I've found while searching for answers and also from my own practices is that Firefox just does not support aria-live on Mac.  Apparently they were trying to make aria work at one time but quit due to a lack of communication with the VoiceOver team.

Thanks anyone who researched or did any testing.

Comment: Six years later, it seems this is still the case :(